# Does my cat have anxiety?

Tags: cats, behavior

A few weeks ago, I moved into my first apartment. I brought my two outdoor cats with me. They were indoor cats, but my mam had a baby years ago and decided she didn't want them in the house anymore. I knew they hated being outside and so was delighted to bring them in. They are 12 and 15 year old respectively, and they love it here! They won't even look outside, just follow me around all day.

My concern is at night my 15 year old, male cat (named Mylo) is perfect during the day and would originally sleep in the living room/kitchen. He started to pee outside the litter box, so I got one with a cover and it went well until he started to pee on the counter! I knew putting him in a different room at night was a bad idea because he cries out non-stop for hours, really loud! We tried having him in our room, but he cries to be in the living room and walks on our faces at night. I know he loves the bed being beside the radiator at night and thought that would be a reason.

I just can't stand the peeing on my counter near appliances. I know he's slightly deaf and very confused and also goes around with his tongue out most of the time after hours of over grooming. I don't like listening to him cry in the bathroom because it breaks my heart. I don't even want to wait until he gets used to it. I just don't understand what to do.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I would do is get Mylo checked out at the vet. There could be several reasons for him peeing outside the litter box. He could have a urinary tract infection, for example, and has learned to associate the discomfort of peeing with the litter box. He could have arthritis, making it difficult to step over the lid of the box. (Although, if he is jumping up on the counter, that might not be the case.) Given his age, a check-up is probably the best place to start.

Next, do you have enough litter boxes? Ideally with two cats there should be three litter boxes, but definitely at least two. Put them in different locations -- perhaps Mylo feels that the litter box is too far away when he needs to pee.

Perhaps Mylo doesn't like the litter. Cats generally prefer litter that is similar in texture to sand. It should be unscented. Try a different litter in each litter box to see which they prefer.

Is the other cat perhaps ambushing Mylo at the litter box? Another reason to have more than one litter box.  Cats tend to prefer open litter boxes, because they can see if someone approaches.

Another possible reason that Mylo is peeing in inappropriate places is that he feels the need to mark his territory. Are there perhaps stray cats outside?

The overgrooming could be stress, or it could be a skin problem (another thing to ask the vet about.)